# Overriding default behavior for Jackson serializers

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, jackson

I am using Jackson to prepare a JSON object to be inserted into ElasticSearch (ES is somewhat unrelated here).  The object looks like:

```
class TimestampedCount {
    private Date timestamp;
    private Map<Long, Integer> counts;
}
```

The default behavior is, as expected, to convert the `counts` variable to an object.  However, due to how I am storing the data in ES, I'd like to coerce the map to a `byte[]` or `String` field, without having to change the defined type.  In other words, I want it stored differently from how it's being used.  For example, if I convert it to a `String`, I'd expect something like the following in the final JSON:

```
{
    "timestamp": 12355812312,
    "counts": "{1: 15431, 2: 15423, 3: 1314}"
}
```

Is there a way to do this without having to write a custom serializer/deserializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add a 'getter' method which would convert the Map into suitable format. Here is an example returning a byte array:

```
public class JacksonGetter {
    static class TimestampedCount {
        private final Date timestamp;
        private final Map<Long, Integer> counts;

        public TimestampedCount(final Date timestamp, final Map<Long, Integer> counts) {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
            this.counts = counts;
        }

        public Date getTimestamp() { return timestamp; }

        @JsonProperty("counts")
        public byte[] getCountsAsBytes() {
            return counts.toString().getBytes();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final TimestampedCount timestampedCount = new TimestampedCount(
                new Date(),
                Collections.singletonMap(1L, 123));
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(timestampedCount));

    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"timestamp":1450555085608,"counts":"ezE9MTIzfQ=="}
```

Comment: Ah, that should have been blatantly obvious.  I'm assuming this works the same for a setter (for coercing it back from the JSON to a POJO).  Thanks for the answer!